# python while loop waiting for a condition change or timeout

Tags: python, timeout, while-loop

I want to construct a while loop in python that waits for some condition (function `foo`) to change, or give a timeout after some specified time. Here is how I would code it

```
def wait_change():
  import time
  timeout = 10 # time out of 10 seconds for example

  # set initial time and initial variables
  start_time = time.time()
  current_time = 0
  start_state = foo()
  current_state = start_state

  while current_time<timeout and start_state==current_state:
    current_time = time.time()-start_time
    current_state = foo()

 if current_time<timeout:
   return None
 else:
   return current_state
```

This function works well, but I am not sure if this is the optimal way to do it. The important thing is that I want to check for some state and return it, and to notify the calling function in case of a timeout (here returning `None`). 
Is this the best implementation, or is there a more pythonic way to handle this? Especially I am concerned

- to have two calls to the function `foo`
- if the return values are appropriate (i.e. wither return the value or `None`)
- if the use of `signal` or `threading` might be more useful leading to better code

Thanks, 
  Alex

Comment: Small note: in your last if statement you probably want to check for `start_state!=current_state` instead, since the state change may have happened just as you timed out.

Comment: @Jonas: thanks that's a good point.

Comment: I would recommend the use of the threading.Event object